# UITableView -- foreshadowing a section move

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, editing

In iOS 5, UITableView has a new `moveSection:toSection:` method that lets you move entire sections.  This is great.  But is there any built-in way for the user to select a section?  Or to graphically foreshadow the move, similar to what happens with a proposed move of a table view row?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I'm not entirely sure what you want here "graphically foreshadow".

Comment: If you move one row to another row, you can see the graphic foreshadowing that Apple does.  It shows the row sliding to the new location while your finger is down, but the move doesn't actually happen until you bring your finger up.

Comment: what you do for moving section?

Comment: Somewhat related to your question, I just wrote up how I handled enabling users to move sections in an answer to the following post. To directly answer the question, I don't know of a built-in way to enable section rearranging, which is why I had to write my own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663369/can-i-drag-sections-in-tableview-as-i-can-do-it-with-rows/